# Hover not work when webkit-app-region is drag

Tags: javascript, css, electron

```css
.title_bar {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  background-color: #050505; 
}

.title_bar:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Hover doesn't work when `-webkit-app-region: drag`, this is expected but how could I get it to work?

The property `-webkit-app-region: drag;` is used to allow the specified area to be dragged across the application window.

By default, this property disables mouse interaction with the area, including the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76221574/2627338