# Webkit-app-region: drag and hover don't work together

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, electron

When building an Electron app, by adding `-webkit-app-region: drag;` an element can be seen that it will drag the app around the desktop, but this element is exempt from properties such as hover, mouseenter, mouseleave, etc...

My goal is to use `-webkit-app-region: drag;` and place a hover over the element, that way when the mouse is on top, in addition to being able to drag the element, it will have a different color.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to designate an element in a HTML document as an [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/) [draggable region](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#set-custom-draggable-region) and have the very same element interactive with properties such as css hover, js mouseenter or js mouseleave events.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like best is to not use `-webkit-app-region: drag` at all and instead switch to a custom IPC event that manually moves the window via some electron APIs.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1354#issuecomment-1067493360